# Proper UFW rules for webserver being tunneled through Openvpn Server on EC2 instance

Tags: iptables, web-server, openvpn, ufw

I have configured a webserver locally. I am running an Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 instance which is configured as an openvpn server. My webserver is successfully connecting/tunneling to my OpenVPN Ubuntu server Instance, and serving web requests on ports 80 (http) and ports 443 (Https). My openvpn client (the web server) is connecting to my openvpn server instance on port 1194/UDP. Without UFW or any firewall whatsoever, my webserver is properly serving traffic through my openvpn instance on EC2. However, on the EC2 instance, when I apply UFW rules to allow for ssh, and allow incoming traffic on ports 443 and 80 for the webserver, my webserver is no longer accessible from the outside. My default incoming rules are deny, and default outgoing rules are allow. Below is my UFW configuration on my openvpn EC2 instance:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
43219                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
1194                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    123.124.1my.1ip
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    123.224.1my.2ip
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    10.8.0.0/24
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
43219 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
1194 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

This configuration is somehow blocking traffic to my webserver through the vpn. So my question is what am i doing wrong? What exactly do I need to unblock in order to get my webserver to pass through the vpn tunnel, out to the rest of the world?

Comment: Avoid redirect-gateway

Comment: Thanks @Tom Yan, but I haven't the slightest clue what that means exactly. Any hints?

Comment: Check your openvpn server conf and see https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/